# Setting ssh or commandline access to windows virtual machine in windows azure

Tags: linux, shell, azure

I have linux and windows vm in Windows Azure. I use ssh to connect to my linux vm and it works fine on command line. For windows vm, i have to use RD services to log into first and then do my work which is complex and not something i want. I would love to have some command line connectivity to my windows vm similar to linux vm so when i connect to my both linux and windows vm, i still use the command windows on my desktop.

How to configure ssh or any command line access to windows vm in windows azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are othe sshd alternatives on windows besides OpenSSH (which is a good choice):
[WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) - free for personal, non-commercial use and [FreeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) which is open source, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), it has an OpenSSH server and is free.

It also installs many command line tools that may be familiar for you (from Linux), like bash, grep, less, sort, tar, gzip, etc.

After installing Cygwin with OpenSSH, run this at the cygwin prompt:

```
ssh-host-config
net start sshd
```